# Predicted target location

Tags: c#, mathematics, xna

I'm having an issue with calculating the predicted linear angle a projectile needs to move in to intersect a moving enemy ship for my 2D game.

I've tried following the document [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Game_Creation_with_XNA/AI/Artificial_Intelligence_in_Games#Calculation_steps), but what I've have come up with is simply awful.

```
protected Vector2 GetPredictedPosition(float angleToEnemy, ShipCompartment origin, ShipCompartment target)
{
    // Below obviously won't compile (document wants a Vector, not sure how to get that from a single float?)
    Vector2 velocity = target.Thrust - 25f; // Closing velocity (25 is example projectile velocity)
    Vector2 distance = target.Position - origin.Position; // Range to close
    double time = distance.Length() / velocity.Length(); // Time

    // Garbage code, doesn't compile, this method is incorrect
    return target.Position + (target.Thrust * time);
}
```

I would be grateful if the community can help point out how this is done correctly.

Comment: You say "document wants a Vector, not sure how to get that from a single float". A speed (or thrust or velocity) can be expressed with a vector too, because a moving object has a (scalar) speed and a direction (unit vector). If you multiply this unit vector with the speed number, you get a speed vector. It tells you the x and the y component of the speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labelling the shooter's position `x`, the target's initial position `y`, the speed of the projectile `v` and the vector velocity of the target `dy` you must choose a unit vector direction `d` to shoot in that satisfies the equations

```
x[0] + v*t*d[0] = y[0] + dy[0]*t
x[1] + v*t*d[1] = y[1] + dy[1]*t
```

for some time to impact `t`. Rearranging yields

```
v*t*d[0] = dy[0]*t + (y[0]-x[0])
v*t*d[1] = dy[1]*t + (y[1]-x[1])
```

Noting that `d` is a unit vector we have

```
d[0]^2 + d[1]^2 == 1
```

and hence

```
(v*t)^2 = (dy[0]*t + (y[0]-x[0]))^2 + (dy[1]*t + (y[1]-x[1]))^2
        = dy[0]^2*t^2 + 2*dy[0]*(y[0]-x[0])*t + (y[0]-x[0])^2
        + dy[1]^2*t^2 + 2*dy[1]*(y[1]-x[1])*t + (y[1]-x[1])^2
```

so

```
a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0
```

where

```
a = v^2 - dy[0]^2 - dy[1]^2
b = -2*dy[0]*(y[0]-x[0]) - 2*dy[1]*(y[1]-x[1])
c = -(y[0]-x[0])^2 - (y[1]-x[1])^2
```

This is a quadratic equation in `t` and has solutions

```
t = (-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)
```

If this doesn't have a positive real solution then you can't hit the target (it's moving too fast). If it does, substitute it back into the rearranged equations to get `d`.
The counter clockwise angle that this makes with the positive x-axis is `Math.Atan2(d[1],d[0])` and the difference between it and the angle in which the shooter is facing is the one you're after.

**UPDATE**: Note that I've assumed that the shooter is stationary. If it's moving and its velocity `dx` should affect that of the projectile, you need to replace `dy[i]` with `(dy[i]-dx[i])` throughout.